# Edit value on mapping with AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to refactor my project and use automapper to map view model to entity model. Here is my my current code. I have used **Guid.NewGuid()**, **GetValueOrDefault()** and **DateTime.Now**. How can I edit those value on mapping?

```
var product = new Product
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Name = model.Name,
    Price = model.Price.GetValueOrDefault(),
    ShortDescription = model.ShortDescription,
    FullDescription = model.FullDescription,
    SEOUrl = model.SEOUrl,
    MetaTitle = model.MetaTitle,
    MetaKeywords = model.MetaKeywords,
    MetaDescription = model.MetaDescription,
    Published = model.Published,
    DateAdded = DateTime.Now,
    DateModified = DateTime.Now
};
```

then here is my map code

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<Product, ProductCreateUpdateModel>().ReverseMap();
});
```

Comment: *edit those value on mapping* What do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell me if I understood you right. You want to create AutoMapper configuration, but some of the properties you want to map manually? In this case, you can do following:

```
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<Product, ProductCreateUpdateModel>()
                .ReverseMap()
                    .ForMember(product => product.Price, expression => expression.MapFrom(model => model.Price.GetValueOrDefault()))
                    .ForMember(product => product.DateAdded, expression => expression.UseValue(DateTime.Now))
                    .ForMember(product => product.DateModified, expression => expression.UseValue(DateTime.Now));
        });
```

If not, please, specify your question.